# Razor Views Agrega Clases css por defecto con @Html.EditorFor - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un `Input` en `Razor` en el cual agregue una clase propia, pero a la hora de ver en la vista parece que `Razor` agrega unas clase extra las cuales no quiero, pero no se como quitar.

Este es mi `Input`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimerNombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "question", @id= "nombreUsuario", @value="" } })
```

Cuando me posiciono en el inspector de elementos veo que a el `Input` se le han adicionado dos clases las cuales, no quiero en dicho `Input`, ¿como las puedo quitar? Solo quiero que la clase `question` este en el `Input`, pero `Razor` me pone esas otras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no es posible para un control Editor quitar esas propiedades, pero puedes crear tu propio Html helper o cambiarlo por TextboxFor al final solo pondras el nombre del usuario un textbox te funcionara mejor que un Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas el *HtmlHelper* **`@Html.EditorFor`** para una propiedad en tu Modelo de datos (en tu caso `PrimerNombre`), estás indicando a Razor que "renderice" el **control HTML más adecuado para esa propiedad en concreto**.

Es por esto que Razor crea **por defecto** un `<input />` con las clases `text-box` y `single-line`, las cuales deberás definir tu mismo si así lo quieres, ya que si te das cuenta, estas clases **no existen** en los archivos `.css` de la aplicación.

Para solucionarlo, utiliza el *HtmlHelper* **`@Html.TextBoxFor`**. De esta manera, estarás indicando a Razor que te cree directamente una etiqueta `<input />`, sin que tome decisiones por ti, y sin incluir esas clases que no sirven para nada.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrimerNombre,  new { @class = "question", @id= "nombreUsuario", @value="" }  )
```